# How can I make a button in GTK Rust look more like a link?

Tags: css, rust, gtk

So I have tried to make a button in a project I am working on in GTK Rust look more like a link using the following:

```css
.MainScreenCpt__button_superman_button {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The corresponding main screen component file with the button with the text of superman looks like this:

```rust
let superman_button = button::create_text_button(self, "superman_button", "Superman");
superman_button.set_halign(gtk::Align::Start);
superman_box.add(&superman_button);
```

The text of underline and cursor pointer in the css selector causes my application to panic and not compile. Is there a way to turn that button to look more like a link?

The error I get when it panics is:

```
(process:1073867): GLib-GIO=CRITICAL **: 19:18:34.262: g_application_set_application_id: assertion 'application_id == NULL || g_application_id_is_valid (application_id)' failed thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { domain: gtk-css-provider-error-quark, code: 3, message: "<data>:8:10'cursor' is not a valid property name" }',
src/main.rs:35:62 note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

So part of the problem was that I was calling the widget name of `superman_button` incorrectly, but even after I corrected that, if I try a

```
.MainScreenCpt__button_superman_button {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I get no response, and yet if I do:

```
.MainScreenCpt__button_superman_button label {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That works, the label gets styled with no issues, but it still looks like a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following which works:

```
.SomeCpt__button_superman_button {
  // styling here 
}

.SomeCpt__button_superman_button:hover {
   color: #409EFF;
   background-color: rgb(236, 245, 255);
}

.SomeCpt__button_superman_button:hover label {
  text-decoration-line: underline; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, it seem to me that you are looking for some solution to make some text clickable (link in HTML). If that's correct then read further.

In below example I used gtk4, but document just that it should work with gtk3 as well.(With some changes in creating application/window object)

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, Button, Inhibit, Label, ListBox};

const APP_ID: &str = "org.gtk_rs.HelloWorld2";

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder().application_id(APP_ID).build();
    app.connect_activate(build_ui);
    app.run();
}
fn build_button_with_label() -> Label {
    let label = Label::new(None);
    label.set_markup("Go to the <a href=\"https://www.gtk.org\" title=\"&lt;i&gt;Our&lt;/i&gt; website\">GTK website</a> for more...");
    label.connect_activate_link(|_label, link_text| {
        println!("Link target is {:?} getting clicked", link_text);
        // Inhibit(false) // return false to call os default behaviour
        Inhibit(true) // return true to not to call os default behaviour
    });
    label
}
fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let button = Button::builder()
        .label("Press me!")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    button.connect_clicked(|button| {
        button.set_label("Hello World!");
    });
    let label = build_button_with_label();
    let list_box = ListBox::new();
    list_box.append(&button);
    list_box.append(&label);

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("My GTK App")
        .child(&list_box)
        .build();
    window.present();
}
```

Comment: if I understand Rust correctly, you are building this link type label with `build_button_with_label`, but my label is inside the `superman_button`. How do I apply that `build_button_with_label` to the `superman_button` in Rust?

Comment: also, being that this is a desktop app of sorts, how do you capture a url to go to? Something I did not think through when I created this question, thats how much of a noob I am.

Comment: Can you change `superman_box.add(&superman_button);` to `superman_box.add(&label);`?

Comment: my superman_button is inside a `create_widget` function. Not sure how to make your solution work in that context.